# Inialize a jQuery textfield-datepicker w/ today's date in the format yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using a jQuery datepicker attached to a text input.  Is there a datepicker action that can inialize the text field w/ today's date (yyyy-mm-dd) when the page loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize the datepicker with the date format and set the date -

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'})
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate" , new Date())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default date to a fixed or relative value:

```
// Only necessary if you are sending data using a different format
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
// Initialize to a fixed date
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: '2011-10-20' });
// or to a relative date
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: +7 });
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-altFormat
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using the datepicker from jQueryUI, you can explicitly set its value directly after initializing it:

```
$('#id').datepicker();
$('#id').datepicker('setDate', new Date);
```