# Cannot change date format for set date - jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to change the date format of a set date to "dd.mm.yy"!

For me it should work like in my code but set date will display "11/19/2011" in place of "19.11.2011"

When I pick a date the format is right!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' });
        $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", "+3");

    });     

 /* German initialisation for the jQuery UI date picker plugin. */
jQuery(function($){
    $.datepicker.regional['de'] = {
        closeText: 'schließen',
        prevText: '&#x3c;zurück',
        nextText: 'Vor&#x3e;',
        currentText: 'heute',
        monthNames: ['Januar','Februar','März','April','Mai','Juni',
        'Juli','August','September','Oktober','November','Dezember'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Feb','Mär','Apr','Mai','Jun',
        'Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dez'],
        dayNames: ['Sonntag','Montag','Dienstag','Mittwoch','Donnerstag','Freitag','Samstag'],
        dayNamesShort: ['So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr','Sa'],
        dayNamesMin: ['So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr','Sa'],
        weekHeader: 'Wo',
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''};
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['de']);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837107/inialize-a-jquery-textfield-datepicker-w-todays-date-in-the-format-yyyy-mm-dd) to see if it helps. It seems the two lines (`$('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", "+3");` and `$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' });`) should be inverted.

Comment: I even try it, but nothing changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get it!!

in this line

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

the datepicker will be initialized! thereby the default date format is used!

that means the format has to be defined direct in the initialization like

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' });
```

or after the initialization via setters

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'dd.mm.yy' );
```

both variants work!

Answer (score 1):

Does this help:

```
$(function() {
       var m = new Date("01","10","2011");
            m = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd MM yy', m);
            $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate",m);
    });
```

The above code worked for me in case of setting date. Hope it works for you too.

Comment: I tried a Fiddle with this code, and didn't work. Could you add one Fiddle with a working code?

Answer (score 1):

'**dd.mm.yy**' is different from '**dd.MM.yy**' 
'**MM**' is for Month

'**mm**' is for minute

see the link
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat for more details.

Comment: -1 As you can read here http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate mm is not for minute its **mm - month of year (two digit)**