# Jqueryui setdate not setting correct date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using rails with jqueryui datepicker.

```
$('#rfq_due').datepicker(dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy')
```

I also have a button that's supposed to set the date to 7/13/2015 but this button sets it to 08/14/2015 instead.

```
<a onclick="$('#rfq_due').datepicker('setDate',' 07/13/15');return false;" class="btn btn-default" href="#">1</a>
```

Comment: I would try removing the blank space and would probably use full year for good measure - '07/13/2015'.  Docs [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate).

Comment: @steveklein It doesn't look like that fixes anything.  With that format, the date is set to "02-03-2021"

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the `dateFormat` - can you try just removing the space so it matches your format?

Comment: Also, I think you are creating a new `datepicker` when `onclick` fires.  If this is the case, you will need to set the `dateFormat` there.  See @burner's answer to his own [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150518/cannot-change-date-format-for-set-date-jquery-datepicker).

Comment: I just changed it to <a onclick="$('#rfq_due').datepicker('setDate','07/13/15');return false;" class="btn btn-default" href="#">1</a>
but there doesn't seem to be a difference

Comment: @steveklein I noticed that the button works as expected if i remove the dateFormat but then rails won't accept it